# Data modeling for comments for posts

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm working on a publishing tool that has a similar structure to blogs, with a user having many posts and posts having comments, and comments each having its owner, etc.

I don't plan to utilize comments in any aggregate way, which means comments will be just displayed when people view the corresponding post, but won't do much else.

I'm thinking about just storing all the comments as a JSON of {timestamp:{user:comment}} items, so for example, like this:

> {{"01-04-12-08" : {"John" : "Hey cool!"} }, {"01-04-12-15":{"Mary" : "No it's not"}}, ... }

Instead of using database tables, it would store the entire data structure as a string, and then later turn it back to JSON when it's needed.

Is it a right way to do something like this? Or should I create database tables? I just felt like creating tables and associations was a bit of an overkill since these comments won't be utilized so much other than just being displayed for each post. Maybe it's not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I just felt like creating tables and associations was a bit of an overkill ...

It's really not. It's just easier to keep comments like the rest of your tabular data, rather than reinventing half a wheel in a JSON store. You just have to write a short migration and a minimal model class to get the whole ActiveRecord bag of tricks. And you get an easier path to upgrades, like threads, notifications, spam filtering, voting, etc.

Comment: Thank you. I guess what I was curious about was not how hard it is to create models, but about how heavy it is. For example in this comment case, I just felt like maintaining multiple columns when I can keep this thing in a single string might be too heavy. Is it generally considered OK to create many tables and columns even when you won't be doing much with them?

Comment: @Vlad, you're being tempted with premature optimization. The bottleneck for most apps isn't db performance, but code complexity. Using the same techniques for all of your persistence helps keep it simple. When your app can't keep up with demand, _then_ experiment with denormalization, etc., as needed.

Comment: Thank you. I guess I will follow your advice and just use tables :)

Answer (score 2):

If you really prefer working with json and not tables, you might look into a document database like [mongodb](http://www.mongodb.org/).  However, in my experience, relational databases are a bit more flexible and rails makes it so easy to talk to them.

Comment: I agree. When I first saw the JSON, I assumed MongoDB.

Comment: Same here, mongodb just came into my mind. Aldo it would just make it more complex i guess. And i don't agree when you say that relational db is more flexible than document based because it isnt, but never tried with rails so in this cause it should be easier

Comment: i dont have tons of experience with document databases so take my opinion with a grain of salt.  however, if you store your objects the default way, where one object is nested in the other as opposed to being related to each other by a key, then you are stuck with retrieving it that way.  If your orders are nested inside each customer for example, you can't get at the orders by themselves directly.  Tables force you to break things up in a more flexible way, IMHO.  A document db may be more convenient in many ways, but not as flexible.